# Uploading files to SharePoint site using GraphAPI

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an outlook add-in that gives the user the option to upload some or all the attachments in the email to a SharePoint site they have access to.
The way I'm doing it is by getting the itemId from Office.context (messageId) API, using it to call Graph API endpoint Attachments, then filtering through the response selecting the attachments i want then uploading it.
However, the files that are being uploaded are empty/corrupted files am I misunderstanding how the endpoint works?

```
const attachments = await client.api(`/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments`).get();

      const files = attachments.value.map((file: any) => ({
        name: file.name,
        attachmentId: file.id,
        content: file.contentBytes,
        size: file.size,
        contentType: file.contentType,
        selected: false,
      }));


const selectedFiles = attachedFiles.filter((file) => file.selected);
    for (const file of selectedFiles) {
      try {
        const response = await client
          .api(`/sites/${siteId}/drive/items/${path}:/${file.name}:/content`)
          .header("Content-Type", "application/" + file.contentType)
          .header("@odata.type", "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment")
          .put(file.content);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to following code to upload file

```
public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context,string uploadFolderUrl, string uploadFilePath)  
{  
    var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation  
    {  
            Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath),  
            Overwrite = true,  
            Url = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath)  
    };  
    var targetFolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uploadFolderUrl);  
    var uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);  
    context.Load(uploadFile);  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
}  
  
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))  
{  
     ctx.Credentials = credentials;  
  
     UploadFile(ctx,"LibName/FolderName/Sub Folder Name/Sub Sub Folder Name/Sub Sub Sub Folder Name",filePath);     
}
```

Here are some quality links for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698

https://medium.com/how-tos/how-to-upload-files-to-onedrive-or-sharepoint-using-microsoft-graph-api-and-csom-1d052b21e0a8

Comment: The code you provided is in CS, and it uses special library my question is about a react project in Typescript.